# Why GCC use '-g' to debug?

Tags: gcc, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments

I'm curious why the developers of GCC choose `-g` rather than `-dbg` or `-d` or others to flag this debug option? What does `-g` really mean?  Does it mean 'generate' or something?

Other related questions:
What do these options mean respectively? Why do they use these characters like 'B', 'E'?

```
  -B <directory>           # Add <directory> to the compiler's search paths.
  -E                       # Preprocess only; do not compile, assemble or link.
```

Maybe they are all because of the historical reasons, which are definitely what I want to know.

Comment: The `-g` flag seems to have been added to `cc` for V8 Unix; it wasn't in V7.  https://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file1=V8/usr/man/man1/cc.1&file2=V7/usr/man/man1/cc.1&print=1  But it certainly predates GCC.

Comment: Note that V7 already had `-E` and `-S`, and something similar to `-B`.  They may go back even further, I didn't check.  `.s` as a suffix for assembly source files goes way way back, so `-S` makes sense to match that.